# jquery ajax call redirects to called url insted of same template

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I have a django form like :

```
<form class="myform" action="{% url "create" %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="results"></div>
    <label class="input margin-bottom-10">{{form.name}}
    <div class="name_error"></div>
    </label>
    <label class="input margin-bottom-10">{{form.age}}
    <div class="age_error"></div>
    </label>
    <input class="margin-top-10 pull-right" type="submit" value="Confirm" >
</form>
```

and my jquery is like:

```
frm = $('.myform')
frm.on('submit', function(event){
    create(frm);
});



function create(frm) {
    $.ajax({
        url : frm.attr('action'), // the endpoint
        type : frm.attr('method'), // http method
        data: frm.serialize(), // data sent with the post request

        // handle a successful response
        success : function(response) {
            if(response.status == "success"){
                var success_message = "<div>some success message</div>)
                $('#container_body').html(success_message);
            };

            if(response.status == "error"){
               frm.find('.results').html("<div class='alert alert-mini alert-danger'>"+response.message+"</div>");
            };
        },
    });
};
```

Here my ajax call is doing good. I am getting proper response but DOM manipulation is wrong..

When I click the submit button and there is error. I want to show the error message on `.results` class.

When there is error the form with error is shown for a while and disappear and my url page with json reponse is shown.

My form with error message did not stay and redirects to the url page with json response.

What is wrong in here

Comment: do you need to pass the entire form as an argument? You can simple pass the form attribute instead of the form

Comment: `<input class="margin-top-10 pull-right" type="button" value="Confirm" >`

Comment: `type="submit"` will submit the form..Or use `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: `frm.on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    create(frm);
});` will help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scripts had JS errors and it is submitted. Here is what you need to do to address this. Read inline comments.

```
frm.on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault(); //Prevents the default action from happening and Rayon mentioned 
  create(frm);
});
```

Fix your JS errors in success function. Remember JS errors may fail your whole app.

```
 success : function(response) {
        if(response.status == "success"){
            var success_message = "<div>some success message</div>"; //This line had error in your code
            $('#container_body').html(success_message);
        } //You don't need a semicolon here

        if(response.status == "error"){
           frm.find('.results').html("<div class='alert alert-mini alert-danger'>"+response.message+"</div>");
        } //You don't need a semicolon here 
    }// You dont need the redundant comma here which will error out in IE
```